# iOS App with Webview inspecting > find URL

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm using an iPhone App that has some important information on it, but I also figured out that it uses a webview. And I'm not sure if it's safe; like; is it over https? What URL is being called?

Is there a way you can find out what Website is being called in the webview? Like you can do inspect element when using Safari from OSX with usb-connected iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

UIWebview works for any url you call it with. If your site is https, the communication will be encrypted. Not all requests on UIWebView are not https. You can't inspect element from iPhone/iPad/Simulator. You can do it in web in the mobile view (by using useragent).